# ERROR:HDLCompilers:26 - expecting 'end', found 'function'

Tags: verilog

```
`timescale 1ns / 1ps
//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
// Company: 
// Engineer: 
// 
// Create Date:    12:08:33 05/01/2021 
// Design Name: 
// Module Name:    postfix 
// Project Name: 
// Target Devices: 
// Tool versions: 
// Description: 
//
// Dependencies: 
//
// Revision: 
// Revision 0.01 - File Created
// Additional Comments: 
//
//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
module postfix(input [7:0]infix,
                    input clk,
                    output reg [7:0]postfix);

reg [7:0]in_val[0:50];
reg [7:0]out_val[0:50];
reg [7:0]stack[0:50];
reg [7:0] ch;
reg [7:0] res;
reg [7:0] temp;
reg [7:0] op1, op2;
reg [3:0] top = 3'b0;
reg [1:0] ch_pr;
reg [1:0] stacktop_pr;
reg [1:0] ret_val = 2'bZ;
reg [1:0] k = 2'b0;
reg done = 1'b0;

integer i = 0;
integer j = 0;
integer l = 0;

parameter  INIT = 1,
       GET_INPUT = 2,
       POP_VAL = 3,
       CHECK_PRECEDENCE = 4,
       COMPARE_PRECEDENCE = 5,
       EMPTY_STACK = 6,
       EVALUATE = 7;
        

reg [3:0] p_s = 3'b0;
reg [3:0] n_s = INIT; 

always @ (infix)
begin
    if (infix != "\0")
    begin
      in_val[l] = infix;
      l = l + 1;    
    end
    if (infix == "=")
    begin               
        done = 1;
        l = 0;
    end 
end 

always@(posedge clk)
begin 
   if(done == 1)
    begin
    p_s = n_s;
    case(p_s)
        INIT: 
        begin                
        stack[top] = "#" ;
          n_s = GET_INPUT;
        end
        GET_INPUT: 
        begin
           if(in_val[i] != "=")
            begin
                ch = in_val[i];
                if(ch == "(") 
                begin                                       
                    top = top+1;
                    stack[top] = ch;
                    i = i+1; 
                    n_s = GET_INPUT; 
                end
                else if (in_val[i] >= "0" && in_val[i] <= "9") 
                begin
                    out_val[j] = ch;
                    j = j + 1;
                    i = i+1; 
                    n_s = GET_INPUT; 
                end
                else if(in_val[i] == ")")
                begin
                   n_s = POP_VAL;
                end
                else
                begin
                   n_s = CHECK_PRECEDENCE;
                end             
            end
            else
            begin
               n_s = EMPTY_STACK; //pop from stack till empty           
            end
        end
        POP_VAL:
        begin
                if(stack[top] != "(")
                begin
                    out_val[j] = stack[top];
                    top = top-1;
                    j = j+1;
                n_s = POP_VAL;
                end
                else
                begin                   
                    top = top-1; //pop out "("
                    i = i+1;                
                    n_s = GET_INPUT;
                end                             
        end
        CHECK_PRECEDENCE:
        begin
             if(k <=1)
             begin
                 if(k == 0)
                    temp = stack[top];
                 else
                    temp = ch;
                
                 case(temp)
                    "#": ret_val = 'b00;     
                    "(": ret_val = 'b01;      
                    "+": ret_val = 'b10;          
                    "-": ret_val = 'b10;
                    "*": ret_val = 'b11;
                    "%": ret_val = 'b11;
                 endcase    
                 
                 if(k == 0)
                    stacktop_pr = ret_val;
                 else
                    ch_pr = ret_val;
                    
                 k = k+1;
                 n_s = CHECK_PRECEDENCE;
            end
            else
            begin
                k = 0;
                n_s = COMPARE_PRECEDENCE;
            end
        end
        COMPARE_PRECEDENCE:
        begin
            if(stacktop_pr >= ch_pr)
           begin
                out_val[j] = stack[top];
                top = top-1;                
                j = j+1;
                n_s = CHECK_PRECEDENCE;
          end
          else
          begin             
                top = top+1;
                stack[top] = ch;
                i = i+1;                
                n_s = GET_INPUT;                                
          end   
        end 
        EMPTY_STACK:
        begin
          if(stack[top] != "#")     // Pop from stack till empty 
          begin
                out_val[j] = stack[top];
                top = top-1;
                j = j+1;
                n_s = EMPTY_STACK; 
          end
          else
          begin     
                i = 0;
                n_s = EVALUATE;
                top=0;
          end
        end
        EVALUATE:
        begin
            if(i< j)
            begin
              if(out_val[i] >= "0" && out_val[i] <= "9")
              begin
                top = top+1;                 
                 stack[top] = out_val[i];
              end
              else 
              begin
                op1 = stack[top] - 48;
                 top = top-1;
                 op2 = stack[top] - 48;
                 case(out_val[i])
                     "+": ch = op1 + op2;
                     "-": ch = op2 - op1;
                     "*": ch = op1 * op2;
                     "%": ch = mod(op1,op2,res);// LINE:212 //
                 endcase
                 stack[top] = ch + 48;               
              end
             i = i+1;
              n_s = EVALUATE;
        end
    
        else
        begin
             postfix = stack[top];
        end
    end
    
  endcase       
end
end
endmodule
module mod(op1,op2,res);

    input [7:0]op1;
    input [7:0]op2;
    output res;
    wire i;
    always@(op1!=0) 
    begin
        for (i = 0; op2>=op1 ; i = i +1) 
        begin
                res = op2 - op1;
        end
    end
```

endmodule

Errors I am getting:

> ERROR:HDLCompilers:26 - "postfix.v" line 212 unexpected token: 'mod'
> ERROR:HDLCompilers:26 - "postfix.v" line 212 expecting ';', found ','
> ERROR:HDLCompilers:26 - "postfix.v" line 212 expecting ':', found ')'

Comment: A good example of a proper mess.

Comment: Please post properly formatted code. This is unreadable.

Comment: Perhaps verilog doesn't allow a function to be defined inside an `ifelse` or a `case` statement. Try shifting the whole `modulo` function outside the module `postfix`.

Comment: One method to debug syntax errors is to start removing parts of the code (e.g. reduce the case to have only one entry) and see if the error persists. Have you tried that ? Use the [edit] link below the question to edit the question to add or change the details in the question. Do not do it in the comments since comments may get deleted later.

Comment: @AJN can you check this once again please

Comment: This is a mess (as in: difficult to read). 
Setting that aside:  several things jump out:
1.  No endmodule statement for "mod" module.

Answer (score 2):

As of "revision 3" of the question, it's still getting stuck at line 212 at the assignment for case "%". The most recent change was replacing "function MODULO" with "mod(op1,op2,res)". But this approach won't work, because Verilog is not a procedural programming language. There aren't functions that return values, there is only a description of hardware which exists for the entire time of the program.

```
     case(out_val[i])
         "+": ch = op1 + op2;
         "-": ch = op2 - op1;
         "*": ch = op1 * op2;
         "%": ch = mod(op1,op2,res);// LINE:212 //
     endcase
```

In a programming language like C++ or Java, this case statement at runtime would select only one one of those expressions to run and assign the value to ch. But in Verilog, this case statement describes part of a multiplexer which selects the value of ch. When the real hardware is running, all of those expressions are evaluated in parallel, because all of that hardware was synthesized.

So to properly implement your approach, the module `mod(op1,op2,res)` that is defined after module postfix, also has to be *instantiated* inside module postfix, so that it will become part of the hardware and produce a result.

First, declare a wire **mod_result** which will be used to connect the output of `mod(op1,op2,res)` to the case "%" assignment in line 212. This wire declaration has to be before the `always`, so it is inside the `module postfix` definition, but not inside the `always` statement.

Next, declare an instance **inst_mod** of the module `mod(op1,op2,res)`, where the instance inputs op1 and op2 are connected to the op1 and op2 wires of `module postfix`, and the res output of **inst_mod** is connected to the wire **mod_result**: `mod inst_mod( .op1(op1), .op2(op2), .res(mod_result));` This instance declaration also has to be before the `always`, so it is inside the `module postfix` definition, but not inside the `always` statement. This instance declaration makes `module mod` part of the required hardware of `module postfix`.

Finally, that line `"%": ch = mod(op1,op2,res);` needs to be replaced with `"%": ch = mod_result;`. This has the effect of connecting your math calculating module `mod` with the multiplexer that selects which expression to assign to `ch`.

See also my general advice on getting help on HDL compiler error messages: https://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/543458/35022